# HttpPostedFileBase No me aparece como tipo de dato para tomar como parámetro

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, mvc

estoy en un proyecto que debería tomar un formulario con datos de usuario entre ellos una imagen para su perfil, estoy buscando en internet como se hace con MVC en su versión 5.0,
encontre que tomando como parametro de la funcion HttpPostedFileBase podria tomar el archivo del input, pero este no me aparece como tipo de dato, hay alguna libreria que tenga que tener? O no se hace asi en esta version, en caso de ser asi como se haria para tomar el archivo y guardarlo en un root carpeta imagenes.
Adjunto imagen con el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya probé con System.Web.Abstractions, System.IO.Abstractions y ninguna me da resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Sysmen.Web esta pero no me aparece la referencia.

Comment: Siempre es buena idea mostrar posibles correcciones. A veces te resuelven el problema y otras no. Posiblemente te diga en qué namespace se encuentra o sino esté faltando alguna referencia.

Comment: Espero no estés escribiendo únicamente "System.Web". Debes **agregar** la referencia

Comment: Así es como esta escrito en la segunda foto, no conozco otra forma **using System.Web**;

Comment: Cuando te vas al Explorador de soluciones - TuProyecto - Referencias, puedes ver `System.Web` en la lista de referencias?

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar HttpPostedFileBase es necesario tener System.Web

```
using System.Web;
```

Visual Studio te resuelve ese problema si usas el atajo: CTRL+.

Luego simplemente haces un SaveAs() del archivo, considerando que se tenga el acceso necesario a la carpeta destino. Si tenes MVC con IIS podes resolver eso con un [Virtual Directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory#:%7E:text=A%20virtual%20directory%20is%20a,a%20local%20or%20remote%20server.)

```
file.SaveAs(fileName);
```

Comment: Ahí actualice la pregunta, el System.Web esta

Comment: Si usas CTRL+. que soluciones te sugiere? Tal vez tengas algún conflicto y la definición de esa clase está en dos librerías.

Comment: Ahí agregue lo que me aparece, y además elimine todas las librerías que no utiliza

Comment: Ahí vi que estás usando ASP.NET Core que no tiene HttpPostedFileBase.

Fijate acá:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1